# JScrollPane doesn't show when using with JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to show a scroll bar next to my text pane but I can't find the reason why it doesn't show.

```
    this.setLayout(null);

    editorPane = new JTextPane();

    size = editorPane.getPreferredSize();
    editorPane.setBounds(17, 12, 533, size.height * 3);
    editorPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    editorPane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    //editorPane.setEditable(false);
    console = editorPane.getStyledDocument();

    scrollConsole = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
    scrollConsole.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    this.add(editorPane);
    this.add(scrollConsole);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

See [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) for more details...

You have two basic mistakes...

1. You've decided to use a `null` layout, but neglected to set the size of the `JScrollPane`
2. You set the `JTextPane` as the view for the `JScrollPane` but then add it to the container, along with the `JScrollPane`.  A component can only belong to a single container, by adding it a second time, you've removed it from the `JScrollPane`

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: My GUI consists of a background image with a set of components that need to be place in precise positions in order to fit with that image. Which would be the way of doing that without a null layout?

Comment: In that case, I might consider using my own, or using `Insets` or `Border`s.  The problem is, a difference in font metrics across systems will change all this and how it looks...